# What language is a .env file written in?

Tags: environment-variables

By convention, what language or syntax is a `.env` file written in?

Is it a `sh` script, a `bash` script, JavaScript, or is it a stripped down no-frills syntax inspired by `sh` syntax?  Are all variables defined strings, or are other variable types supported?

I recently started using `.env` files in my NodeJS applications, but I can find nowhere in the documentation what language it is in or what constraints on syntax I must follow.  I found a definition in the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/) which seems to suggest `MY_VAR=my val` is the only notable feature, per se.

EDIT:

While I encountered this in the context of NodeJS, the question is not specific to nodeJS.  `.env` files used in other contexts should be considered.

Comment: if your question is specific to node.js, you may find the information you're looking for here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules

Comment: From my point of view, It is not a programming language and it is a file containing different environment variables which is usually a key/value pair.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you're referring to how the .env file is interpreted by the npm dotenv package:

The file simply serves as a 'text' configuration, which is parsed by the module. The parsed configuration is used as a basis for adding environment variables. So the env file itself is not really written in any programming language.

Parsing rules can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#rules

Parsing code can be found here: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/lib/main.js

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful.  It grabs the key-value pairs with the regex `/^\s*([\w.-]+)\s*=\s*(.*)?\s*$/`, and then the value is trimmed among other things.  The value is always a string.

Answer (score 9):

Here are the rules, copy-pasted [from link above](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/blob/master/README.md).  Feel free to update anytime ("Commnity wiki").

---

### Rules

The parsing engine currently supports the following rules:

- `BASIC=basic` becomes `{BASIC: 'basic'}`
- empty lines are skipped
- lines beginning with `#` are treated as comments
- empty values become empty strings (`EMPTY=` becomes `{EMPTY: ''}`)
- inner quotes are maintained (think JSON) (`JSON={"foo": "bar"}` becomes `{JSON:"{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"`)
- whitespace is removed from both ends of unquoted values (see more on [`trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)) (`FOO=  some value`   becomes `{FOO: 'some value'}`)
- single and double quoted values are escaped (`SINGLE_QUOTE='quoted'` becomes `{SINGLE_QUOTE: "quoted"}`)
- single and double quoted values maintain whitespace from both ends (`FOO="  some value  "` becomes `{FOO: '  some value  '}`)
- double quoted values expand new lines, `MULTILINE="new\nline"` becomes

  ```
  {MULTILINE: 'new
  line'}
  ```

Comment: This differs from the rules stated on VSCode Python .env documentation.  I believe VSCode python extension is using npm dotenv or something equivalent, b/c it describes the double-quoting behavior I'm seeing.  But docs say no quoting.