# how to set environment variable from terminal in windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, windows, express

I am following a node course and while setting the environment variable as shown it does not work

It says to set environment variables, use `SET` on Windows and `EXPORT` on Mac:

`set jwtkey=myprivatekey`, when I use this nothing happens, it does not set anything.

This is set using the config package, and I have also created a separate files for `default.json` and `custom-env.json`

```
if (!config.get("jwtPrivateKey")) {
    console.error("FATAL ERROR: JwtKey Not Set");
    process.exit(1);
}
```

please help

this is my .env file(using dotenv)

```
PORT=9000 //this is working
jwtPrivateKey="myPrivateKey" //this is not working tho.
```

[basically, I wanted to hide my VERIFY SIGNATURE(digital signature) and store it in ENV so that it cant be accessed.]

Comment: did you enable `dotenv` like this : `require('dotenv').config()`?

Comment: As I mentioned I am using custom PORT which is working which means dotenv is working fine

Answer (score -1):

I would do it differently.

1. Create a `.env` file in your server root.
2. Add the key/value pair:

   ```
   JWT_PRIVATE_KEY="936392a8c..."
   ```
3. Install [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), and import it.
4. Access `process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY` from anywhere in your server app.

([based on this article](https://towardsdev.com/jwt-authentication-with-node-js-and-react-dc41ef0e6136).)

Comment: I have done this already but not working I am using dotenv for PORT but when I try doing this is its not working

Answer (score -1):

If you use set in a Windows terminal, it will set the variable just for this terminal. If you start the node in the same terminal, everything should work fine. Otherwise read [this article](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html) on how to change the variable permanently.

There are two types of environment variables in Windows: user and system variables. If possible, use a user variable.

You might want to read the answers to this [similar question](https://superuser.com/q/949560)

**Update** (.env)

When using dotenv to read an .env-file as suggestd by Andy, be aware of the parsing rules and make sure that the file encoding is correct; see answers to [What language is a .env file written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56808232/11934850).

Be sure that you use the same variable name in .env and in your code and comments. (You did use jwtkey, JwtKey and jwtPrivateKey.) I also recommend that you use UPPER_CASE for environment variables, just to make sure that case does not matter when switching operating systems. Using the same conventions as the node.js documentation is always a good idea. ([How to read environment variables from Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs).)